# org-table-copy-down for dates

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Suppose I have an org-table like this:

```
| 2018-09-09 |        |        |        |        |         
| 2018-09-10 |        |        |        |        |  
| 2018-09-11 |        |        |        |        |   
|          X |        |        |        |        |
```

X marks the location of the caret. If I invoke `org-table-copy-down` (shift+enter) 1998 will be inserted in the current cell. I suppose because 1998 = 2018-9-11. How can I get it to insert `2018-09-12` instead? I'm hoping that org-mode can be smart enough to understand that the column is about dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mark them as dates: `<2018-09-11>`. See [Dates and times](https://orgmode.org/manual/index.html#toc-Dates-and-times-1). You can change the increment in the usual way, by customizing `org-table-copy-increment` which in the case of dates is in units of days.

EDIT: Here's an example as requested:

```
| Date             | what |
|------------------+------|
| <2018-10-01>     | foo  |
| X                | bar  |
```

With the cursor at X, pressing `S-RET` fills in the next day:

```
| Date             | what |
|------------------+------|
| <2018-10-01>     | foo  |
| <2018-10-02 Tue> | bar  |
```

More `S-RET` keep filling in more dates.

This assumes that `org-table-copy-increment` has the default value of `t`. If it is set to nil:

```
 #+begin_src emacs-lisp
 (setq org-table-copy-increment nil)
 #+begin_src emacs-lisp
```

then no increment is applied when you press `S-RET` and you get the same date that you started with.

If you set it to a number (e.g 2):

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq org-table-copy-increment 2)
#+end_src
```

then `S-RET` incements by two days every time.

UPDATE: you can also use "inactive" dates like this `[2018-10-01]` with square brackets instead of angle brackets, but org mode needs *some* markup to recognize dates.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: Does the edit help?

Comment: Thank you, but why do I have to use angle brackets around the dates?

Comment: That's how org-mode recognizes dates. Read the "Dates and times" link that I included in my answer.

Comment: BTW, if you insert a date with e.g. `C-c .` you will get `<2018-10-02 Tue>` - the angle brackets are part of the date spec.

Comment: Oh ic, that is a weak part of org because the angle brackets look ugly in tables.